# Update table with loop

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, iteration

Hi I  would like to update a column by selecting minimum value  in that column in each iteration and increasing it by 10% till the total sum of column becomes a particular value (say 3000)

```
UPDATE db1.tb1 a 
SET    a.col1 = IF(SUM(a.col1) < 3000, a.col1 + ( a.col1 / 10 ), a.col1) 
WHERE  a.col1 IN (SELECT Min(b.col1) 
                  FROM   (SELECT col1, 
                                 col2 
                          FROM   db1.tb1), 
                         b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in a single `update` statement.  You can repeated loop.  Each iteration would look more like this:

```
update tb1.tbl t cross join
       (select min(col1) as min1, sum(col1) as sum1
        from tb1.tbl
       ) tt
    set col1 = 1.1 * col1
    where tt.sum1 < 3000 and t.col1 = tt.min1
    limit 1;
```

Note the `limit 1` so only one row is updated.  You can then count the number of modified rows (using `mysql_affected_rows()` for instance).  When it is 0, then stop.

You can also set this up in a MySQL stored procedure, if you want to do the looping in MySQL.